# Creating file download functionality

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to create download functionality in an MVC action, and the actual download works, but the file is saved with the actionname as the filename e.g. from the code below I get a filename of 'DownloadMP3'.  Does anybody know how to keep the original filename when downloading?

```
[Authorize]
    public virtual FileResult DownloadMP3(string fileName)
    {
        //Actions/Download?filename=test

        //test 
        string filePath = @"~/Content/xxxxx/" + fileName + ".mp3";

        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;" + filePath + ";");

        return File(filePath, "audio/mpeg3");

        //for wav use audio/wav

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax of the Content-Disposition header is like this:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=foo.mp3
```

But in this case you could simply use the overload of the File method which takes 3 arguments, the third being the filename. It will automatically emit the Content-Disposition header with attachment so that you don't need to manually add it (and make mistakes in its syntax as you did).

Also your `filePath` variable must point to the physical file on the server and not a relative url. Use `Server.MapPath` for this:

```
public virtual ActionResult DownloadMP3(string fileName)
{
    var downloadPath = Server.MapPath("~/Content/xxxxx/");
    fileName = Path.ChangeExtension(Path.GetFileName(fileName), "mp3");
    var file = Path.Combine(downloadPath, fileName);
    return File(file, "audio/mpeg3", fileName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put the file name in the content disposition, not the virtual path:

```
    string fileOnly = fileName + ".mp3";
    string filePath = @"~/Content/xxxxx/" + fileOnly;

    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;" + fileOnly + ";");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to Add third parameter

```
return File(file.FullPath, file.MimeType, file.FullName);
```